# Easiest way to retrieve values from D365 dataverse JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've recently started working with JSON structures from `Microsoft Dynamics 365 dataverse`. A lot of their odata is structured like this:

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://....",
   "value":[
      {
         "@odata.etag":"W/\"Jz....",
         "dataAreaId":"foo",
         "ItemNumber":"TEST",
         "IsPhantom":"No"
      }
   ]
}
```

I simply want to get the value of `ItemNumber`, which in this case is `TEST`. This seems like it should be very simple, but after an hour and a dozen different approaches, I'm wondering what I'm missing.

When using `Newtsonsoft`, it seems like all their approaches require a fully-baked class that perfectly matches the json structure, and the correct specification of complex combinations of `<T>`. This is tedious because I work with many different json data sets and almost all are different from each other in terms of the attributes and their types. I tried things like:

```
dynamic try1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResult);

dynamic try2 = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);

dynamic try3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonResult, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

JObject try4 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResult);
```

Then I gave up on Newtonsoft and tried `JavaScriptSerializer`, but ran into similar dead ends.

```
var try5 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonResult);
string try6 = Utilities.SafeTrim(jsonObj["value"]);
```

In every case I end up with a valid object, but I can never figure out how to traverse down into the object and grab the value I want. I frequently end up with completely useless constructs like this from the VS watch window, which it delivers just to mock me:

```
new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>>(new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>>(try1).Items[1]).Value).Items[0]).Items[2]
```

I'm sure someone has the correct and elegant way to solve this, which would be fine. But what I would really love is a way to take any JSON string and convert to an object, array, or collection that I can easily tease out any value with nested array syntax (or something equally simple). So for my example, maybe something like this:

```
jsonObject["value"]["ItemNumber"]
```

Is something like that so difficult?

Comment: in your case it would be `jsonObject["value"][0]["ItemNumber"]` - but yes it works without any problem...

Comment: no, that doesn't work.

Comment: I'll put the code as answer, just because it's easier to format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
const string jsonInput = @"{
    'odata.context':'https://....',
    'value':[{
        '@odata.etag':'W/z....',
        'dataAreaId':'foo',
       'ItemNumber':'TEST',
       'IsPhantom':'No'
}]}";

dynamic try1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput)!;
Console.WriteLine(try1["value"][0]["ItemNumber"]);
```

returns

> TEST

as expected